# Can Execute trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I'm trying to create a simple trigger to update a table's column after it was inserted.

But when I execute the trigger it produces an error:

> Cannot execute script. Additional information: Unable to start
>   Transct-SQL debugger. The Transact-SQL debugger does not support SQL
>   Server 2005 or earlier versions of SQL Server. (SQLEditors)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here's my simple trigger just to check if it execute.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrCheckFile 
ON CheckFile
FOR INSERT
AS  
        PRINT 'New Check has been issued'
```

Comment: I run your code sample, works OK. MSSQL 2008 R2, Management Studio Express 2012: `Create table x (y varchar(100)); go; CREATE TRIGGER tgrCheckFile ON x FOR INSERT AS PRINT 'New Check has been issued'; go; insert into x values ('xxx');` In Messages windows appear: ` New Check has been issued (1 row(s) affected)` So I think this code is not a problem.

Comment: @Latagaw-- I think its not the error related to creating trigger: You generally get that error, when you connect an instance of 2005 from sql 2008/2008R2 SSMS. If you have recently installed sql server 2008, make sure once the restart had been done. Or other way around use sql server 2005 to connect to this sql 2005 instance. Kindly check and let me know

Comment: yeah @Mikrobi, i tried it and it runs. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put this in a comment but I want to give pictures.

My guess is that you are hitting the little green arrow, or DEBUG button

[image]

Instead of the red exclamation point, or RUN button.

[image]

It's a fairly common mistake.  FYI you can also hit Ctrl-E to "execute" the script or Alt-F5 to "debug" it.  The [TSQL debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645997.aspx) requires elevated rights (sysadmin if I remember correctly) and as you saw doesn't work in versions prior to 2008.

Comment: i notice now that this two button are different. thanks kenneth